# Wordpress Sub Menu Options Page with Tabs

Tags: php, wordpress

I have not been able to find a suitable answer on the web for what I am trying to do. I have created a custom post type "donation" and under that, have a submenu of "settings". I want the settings page to use tabs for different things to keep it simple.

Here is what I have:

```
<?php
function sg_settings_setup()
{
    add_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=donation', 'Settings', 'Settings', 'manage_options', 'sg-settings', 'sg_settings_page');
}

function sg_settings_page()
{
?>

      <div class="wrap">
        <h1>Main Title</h1>

        <?php
    settings_errors();
?>

        <?php
    $active_tab = isset($_GET['tab']) ? $_GET['tab'] : 'general-settings';
?>

        <h2 class="nav-tab-wrapper">
          <a href="?page=sg-settings&tab=general-settings" class="nav-tab <?php
    echo $active_tab == 'general-settings' ? 'nav-tab-active' : '';
?>">General Settings</a>
          <a href="?page=sg-settings&tab=email-settings" class="nav-tab <?php
    echo $active_tab == 'email-settings' ? 'nav-tab-active' : '';
?>">Email Settings</a>
          <a href="?page=sg-settings&tab=stripe-settings" class="nav-tab <?php
    echo $active_tab == 'stripe-settings' ? 'nav-tab-active' : '';
?>">API Settings</a>
        </h2>

        <form method="post" action="options.php">
          <?php
    settings_fields('sg_api_settings');
?>
         <?php
    do_settings_sections('sg_api_settings');
?>
         <?php
    submit_button();
?>
       </form>
      </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

When I click on a tab, I get the error message "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page." I can see in the address bar that the URL is being rewritten where it no longer has "edit.php?post_type=donation" in the URL. I tried adding this to the links for the tabs, but it gets edited out by Wordpress.

I can make this work if the settings page is a menu_page, but the URL somehow needs to be rewritten for submenu_page. Hopefully someone else has run into this and knows a quick fix!

Comment: That's not correct for an options page. And also has nothing to do with the page URL being rewritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I couldn't find a way to make this work using the Wordpress API, I know for example WooCommerce is able to make this work, but since no one replied to my question, I decided to use jQuery instead.  Using the built in Wordpress classes it is easy to style it for a native Wordpress look.

Wrap the tab links in `<h2 class="nav-tab-wrapper">`

Give each tab link a class of `nav-tab`

Make sure "active" tabs have a class of `nav-tab-active`

I created this simple jQuery function:

```
$('#tabs .tab-content').hide();
$('#tabs .tab-content:first').show();
$('.nav-tab-wrapper a:first').addClass('nav-tab-active');

$(".nav-tab-wrapper").on("click", ".nav-tab", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $(".nav-tab a").removeClass("nav-tab-active");
  $(".tab-content").hide();
  $(this).addClass("nav-tab-active");
  $($(this).attr("href")).show();
});
```

And here is some sample HTML:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <h2 class="nav-tab-wrapper">
    <a href="#tab-1" class="nav-tab">One Time Donation</a>
    <a href="#tab-2" class="nav-tab">Recurring Donation</a>
    <a href="#tab-3" class="nav-tab">My Account</a>
  </h2>

  <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content">
    tab 1 content
  </div>
  <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
    tab 2 content
  </div>
  <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
    tab 3 content
  </div>
</div>
```

I wrapped my html in `<div id="tabs">` but this is not required.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the same way you would use `$_GET[ 'tab' ]` to display the individual tabs by using the query string you also need to use `$_GET[ 'tab' ]` to stop the extraneous fields from displaying via the callback of the `add_submenu_page()`.

So what you end up with is something like this:

```
    add_action('admin_menu', 'your_submenu_page');
        
    function your_submenu_page() {
            add_submenu_page( 'top_level_menu', 'Title', 'Header', 'manage_options', 'submenu_slug', 'submenu_callback' );
        }
    
    add_action('admin_init', 'submenu_fields_register');
    function submenu_fields_register(){ 
        $active_tab = isset( $_GET[ 'tab' ] ) ? $_GET[ 'tab' ] : 'first_tab';
        
        if( isset( $_GET[ 'tab' ] ) ) {
            $active_tab = $_GET[ 'tab' ];
        } // end if
    
        if($active_tab == 'first_tab') {
        register_setting('option_group1', 'option_name');
        add_settings_field(
                'first_tab_fields_slug', 
                'First Tab Fields Title',
                'tab_fields_callback',
                'submenu_slug',
                'first_tab_section', 
                );
        add_settings_section(
            'first_tab_section',
            'First Tab Titles',
            'tab_fields_callback',
            'submenu_slug',
        );
            } 
        elseif($active_tab == 'second_tab') {
        register_setting('option_group2', 'option_name');
        add_settings_field(
                'second_tab_fields_slug', 
                'Second Tab Fields Title',
                'tab_fields_callback',
                'submenu_slug',
                'second_tab_section', 
                );
        add_settings_section(
            'second_tab_section',
            'Second Tab Titles',
            'tab_fields_callback',
            'submenu_slug',
        );
            }
         //and so on...
    }

function submenu_callback() {
    $active_tab = isset( $_GET[ 'tab' ] ) ? $_GET[ 'tab' ] : 'first_tab';
?>
    <!-- Create a header in the default WordPress 'wrap' container -->
    <div class="wrap">
     
        <div id="icon-themes" class="icon32"></div>
        <h2>This is My Sub-Menu Page</h2>
        <?php settings_errors();
        
            if( isset( $_GET[ 'tab' ] ) ) {
                $active_tab = $_GET[ 'tab' ];
            } // end if
        ?>
        <h2 class="nav-tab-wrapper">
            <a href="?page=submenu_slug&tab=first_tab" class="nav-tab <?php echo $active_tab == 'multi_order' ? 'nav-tab-active' : ''; ?>">First Tab</a>
            <a href="?page=submenu_slug&tab=second_tab" class="nav-tab <?php echo $active_tab == 'bulk_shipping' ? 'nav-tab-active' : ''; ?>">Second Tab</a>
        </h2>
         
<form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php
    if($active_tab == 'first_tab') {
        settings_fields( 'option_group1' );
        do_settings_sections( 'submenu_slug' );
        } 
    elseif($active_tab == 'second_tab') {
        settings_fields( 'option_group2' );
        do_settings_sections( 'submenu_slug' );
        }
    //And so on...
         
        submit_button();
         
    ?>
</form>
         
    </div><!-- /.wrap -->
<?php
}
```

The original bit of code I used was from [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-wordpress-settings-api-part-5-tabbed-navigation-for-settings--wp-24971), but since it was using a top-level menu page as it's starting point I had to re-factor it a bit so it would work on a sub-menu as well.